# rails doesn't load application layout for views. Where should I look? how to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started a new rails application and switched templating engine from erb to haml.
I added to the Gemfile the haml parser, run bundle install, deleted the app/views/layout/application.html.erb file and replaced it with an haml equivalent.
I got no error message, other haml views are correctly rendered in browser but content in application.html.haml is ignored: if I view the source of generated pages, they miss markup from application.html.haml
any idea on where I should look?

application.html.haml

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Title
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags

  %body
    %h1.title Title
    #main
      - if flash[:notice]
        #notice.message= flash[:notice]
      - elsif flash[:warning]
        #warning.message= flash[:warning]

      = yield
```

GEMFILE

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'haml'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'ruby-debug19'
end
```

Comment: Since the content from the other views would be rendered with the "yield" call in your layout, it must be rendering a layout from somewhere. Do you have any other files in your layouts directory?

Comment: in my app/views/layouts directory I have the application.html.haml file only

Comment: What steps did you take to switch the templating engine to haml? Can you post that code?

Comment: Have you restarted your server since installing adding the haml gem?

Comment: to switch templating engine I simpy edited the Gemfile (it works for views but doesn't for application.html.haml) I restarted rails server many times

Comment: Can you show us the source from a generated view?

Comment: generated views contains only makup from views/my-controller/my-view.html.haml that is for example they start with <h2>title</h2> <p> content </p>

Comment: You don't call the render with `:layout => false` ?

Comment: no I don't call the render with :layout => false

Comment: Why do you have a `5` on the first line - I think you only need `!!!` to set the Doctype. Also you should use the `haml-rails` gem in preference to the `haml` gem.

Comment: switching from haml gem to haml-rails doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What happens if you add `layout "application"` to your controller?

Comment: Also, I can easily duplicate this behaviour by renaming/removing my application.html.haml. No error appears in the console. I hate to suggest checking the spelling of the file name but I just did. What happens if you use an application.html.erb file?

Comment: I tried to put back the original erb file that rails automatically generated but nothing happens. It seems to me that things started going wrong when I renamed the .erb in .erb.somethingElse and added the equivalent .haml file

Comment: Does this error reproduce if you create a project from scratch?

Comment: I had a very similar issue. Suddenly, my haml layout was ignored and css/js files included anymore. It turned out that I added a constructor to my controller. After removing it, everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure your controller inherits from `ApplicationController` class.

Comment: yes, thanks! I inherited from ActionController::Base... don't ask why

Answer (score 0):

One other way this might happen is if you're calling your pages via partial. Partials don't touch application layout, even if you call render partial inside of your controller.
So if you need a file to load within the application layout and it's a partial, change it to a normal html.erb and it will load within application layout. Yay!